# How to format output into 6 columns?

Tags: c

MY output is 285 numbers but its all under column1(in ascending order). It is somehow supposed to be split into 50 numbers for the first 5 columns and then 35 for the last one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX_SIZE_FLOAT n
#define MAX_NUM_OF_FLOATS 1000
void swap(float * a, float * b);`enter code here`
void sort(float ary [], int numElements );
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int i,num_read;
float x, n;
float a[MAX_NUM_OF_FLOATS];`enter code here`
double x1,x2,mn;
FILE * inFile;
inFile = fopen("DataFloat.txt", "r");
if( inFile == NULL) {
    printf("\nError opening input file; program aborted\n");
    exit(1);
}
i = 0;
while( fscanf(inFile, "%f", & a[i]) == 1 ){
    x1+=a[i];
  x2+=a[i]*a[i];
    i++;       
  mn=x1/(double)n;
  }
  fclose(inFile);
   if(n<1){
   printf("\nError.");
    exit(1);
   }  
   num_read = i;
      for(i = 0; i < num_read; i++)

sort(a, num_read);

printf("Column1    Column2   Column3   Column4   Column5   Column6\n",a[i]);
   for(i = 0; i < num_read; i++) <--Am i supposed to be using a for loop here or while-loop?
   printf("%5.2f\n", a[i] );
   return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}  // end of main

void sort(float ary [], int numElements ) {
 int i, currentIndex, foundIndex, nextIndex;
 float min;

// the outer for-loop is the placement loop
for( currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < numElements - 1; currentIndex++){
    min = ary[currentIndex];
    foundIndex = currentIndex;
    nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;

    // the inner for-loop selects the best element from the rest of ary
    for( i = nextIndex; i < numElements; i++)
        if( ary[i] < min ){
            min = ary[i];
            foundIndex = i;
        }
    swap(& ary[currentIndex], & ary[foundIndex]);
}
}

void swap(float * a, float * b){
float temp;
temp = *a;
*a = *b;
*b =temp;
}
```

MY output is 285 numbers but its all under column1(in ascending order). It is somehow supposed to be split into 50 numbers for the first 5 columns and then 35 for the last one.

Comment: How should the numbers read in the columns? Across or down?

Comment: It should read down. The first column should have the first 50 numbers than in column2 it should continue from 51 and so on until comlumn6 where it will have only 35 numbers due to the odd numbers the text file has.

Comment: I did some searching on this site. Is this how i should put this so that i get it like this?                                        while (some_condition)
{
  bread();
  bwrite();
  pgsize();
}
and you want to display the outputs of those functions as

bread    bwrite    pgsize
1234     5678      1024
2345     6789      1024

Comment: How firmly fixed are the values 285, 50, and 6 (the number of columns)? More usually, you'd make the columns as even as possible, with the last column being 0..5 values shorter than the others, rather than 15 values shorter.

Comment: They are floating point numbers(rounded after 2 decimal places) if that's what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine, then, that you would simply format your output with six columns in it, something like

```
for (i = 0; i < 50; ++i){
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d",
           arr[i], arr[i + 50], arr[i + 100], arr[i + 150], arr[i + 200]);
    if(i < 35)
        printf("\t%d", arr[i + 250]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

EDIT: Updated according to Jonathan Leffler's comment.

Comment: The ternary operator is not going to compile, much less work correctly at runtime if it compiled.  Using this basic schema, you're going to need to use two separate `printf()` statements, one for printing 6 columns, one for printing 5.

Comment: There is a random column of 0.00, what is making that happen?

Comment: Where is your bonus column?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (according to my understanding of the problem).  I've parameterized the code so that the number of values, number of columns, and number of complete rows are named constants.  There's an assertion that ensures that Column6 contains some data. The code does not generate the column headings dynamically, but it would not be hard to make it do so.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum { NUM_VALUES  = 285 };
enum { NUM_COLUMNS =   6 };
enum { NUM_ROWS    =  50 };

int main(void)
{
    double data[NUM_VALUES];
    int i;

    assert(NUM_VALUES > (NUM_COLUMNS - 1) * NUM_ROWS &&
           NUM_VALUES <= (NUM_COLUMNS) * NUM_ROWS);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALUES; i++)
        data[i] = i * 10.0 + i / 100.0;

    printf("Column1   Column2   Column3   Column4   Column5   Column6\n");
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++)
    {
        char *pad = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            int index = j * NUM_ROWS + i;
            if (index < NUM_VALUES)
                printf("%s%7.2f", pad, data[index]);
            pad = "   ";                 
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Column1   Column2   Column3   Column4   Column5   Column6
   0.00    500.50   1001.00   1501.50   2002.00   2502.50
  10.01    510.51   1011.01   1511.51   2012.01   2512.51
  20.02    520.52   1021.02   1521.52   2022.02   2522.52
  30.03    530.53   1031.03   1531.53   2032.03   2532.53
  40.04    540.54   1041.04   1541.54   2042.04   2542.54
  50.05    550.55   1051.05   1551.55   2052.05   2552.55
  60.06    560.56   1061.06   1561.56   2062.06   2562.56
  70.07    570.57   1071.07   1571.57   2072.07   2572.57
  80.08    580.58   1081.08   1581.58   2082.08   2582.58
  90.09    590.59   1091.09   1591.59   2092.09   2592.59
 100.10    600.60   1101.10   1601.60   2102.10   2602.60
 110.11    610.61   1111.11   1611.61   2112.11   2612.61
 120.12    620.62   1121.12   1621.62   2122.12   2622.62
 130.13    630.63   1131.13   1631.63   2132.13   2632.63
 140.14    640.64   1141.14   1641.64   2142.14   2642.64
 150.15    650.65   1151.15   1651.65   2152.15   2652.65
 160.16    660.66   1161.16   1661.66   2162.16   2662.66
 170.17    670.67   1171.17   1671.67   2172.17   2672.67
 180.18    680.68   1181.18   1681.68   2182.18   2682.68
 190.19    690.69   1191.19   1691.69   2192.19   2692.69
 200.20    700.70   1201.20   1701.70   2202.20   2702.70
 210.21    710.71   1211.21   1711.71   2212.21   2712.71
 220.22    720.72   1221.22   1721.72   2222.22   2722.72
 230.23    730.73   1231.23   1731.73   2232.23   2732.73
 240.24    740.74   1241.24   1741.74   2242.24   2742.74
 250.25    750.75   1251.25   1751.75   2252.25   2752.75
 260.26    760.76   1261.26   1761.76   2262.26   2762.76
 270.27    770.77   1271.27   1771.77   2272.27   2772.77
 280.28    780.78   1281.28   1781.78   2282.28   2782.78
 290.29    790.79   1291.29   1791.79   2292.29   2792.79
 300.30    800.80   1301.30   1801.80   2302.30   2802.80
 310.31    810.81   1311.31   1811.81   2312.31   2812.81
 320.32    820.82   1321.32   1821.82   2322.32   2822.82
 330.33    830.83   1331.33   1831.83   2332.33   2832.83
 340.34    840.84   1341.34   1841.84   2342.34   2842.84
 350.35    850.85   1351.35   1851.85   2352.35
 360.36    860.86   1361.36   1861.86   2362.36
 370.37    870.87   1371.37   1871.87   2372.37
 380.38    880.88   1381.38   1881.88   2382.38
 390.39    890.89   1391.39   1891.89   2392.39
 400.40    900.90   1401.40   1901.90   2402.40
 410.41    910.91   1411.41   1911.91   2412.41
 420.42    920.92   1421.42   1921.92   2422.42
 430.43    930.93   1431.43   1931.93   2432.43
 440.44    940.94   1441.44   1941.94   2442.44
 450.45    950.95   1451.45   1951.95   2452.45
 460.46    960.96   1461.46   1961.96   2462.46
 470.47    970.97   1471.47   1971.97   2472.47
 480.48    980.98   1481.48   1981.98   2482.48
 490.49    990.99   1491.49   1991.99   2492.49
```